# Probability that two random permutations of an $n$-set commute?

Tags: probability, group-theory, reference-request, permutations

From [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/143058/48278):

> It is well known that two randomly chosen permutations of $n$ symbols commute with probability $p_n/n!$ where $p_n$ is the number of partitions of $n$. -- Benjamin Steinberg

Unfortunately, it's not well known to me.  Can I get a reference or link to this result?  Or a proof, if it's simple enough.

(Google doesn't work where I am; I tried Binging `two random permutations commute` but it only gives the MathOverflow link.)

I need this result for a secret sharing scheme I'm currently analyzing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple matter of combining two other well-known facts:

1. In any finite group $G$, the probability that $a,b$ commute, with $(a,b)\in G\times G$ chosen uniformly at random, is $k/G$, where $k$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$.
2. Conjugacy classes in $S_n$ correspond to cycle types, which correspond to integer partitions.

For fact one, see the very end of [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846217/prove-if-a-b-in-g-commute-with-probability-5-8-then-g-is-abelian/846267#846267). One easily finds proofs and discussions of the second fact googling "conjugacy classes symmetric group," for instance [this one](http://www.math.wm.edu/~vinroot/415conj.pdf).

Comment: Understood!  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a bit more detail to blue's answer, for a finite group $G$, the probability that two randomly chosen elements commute is

$$\frac{1}{|G|^2}\sum_{g \in G} |C_G(g)| = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \frac{1}{|{\rm Cl}(g)|} = \frac{k}{|G|}$$

where $k$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$.

Comment: And thanks here too!