# Given a random binary operation $\varphi$ on a finite set $G$, what is the probability that $(G,\varphi)$ is a group?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

I recently learned about the 5/8 theorem, which states that if the probability that any two random elements in a group commute exceeds 5/8, then the group must be abelian.
I think its interesting seeing probability and group theory together, which led me to think of this question.

This is my work so far, which has a good possibility of being flawed.
First, consider all binary operations $\varphi : G\times G \to G$, which given $|G|=n$ we can count as $|G|^{|G\times G|^2} = n^{n^2}$.

Next, consider all binary operations that fail to have an identity $e \in G$.
If $\varphi(g,e)\neq g$ (or $\varphi(e,g)\neq g$) for any single $g \in G$, we can throw out all other possible functions given by the other elements in $G- \{g\}$, which is given by $(n-1)^{(n-1)^2}$ operations.
There are $n^2$ elements in $|G\times G|$ that each have $(n-1)$ ways to fail, so the number of binary operations that fail to have an identity element should be given by
$$n^2(n-1)(n-1)^{(n-1)^2}=n^2(n-1)^{(n-1)^2+1}$$
Hence, we can get an upper bound for how many binary operations can form groups as
$$n^{n^2}-n^2(n-1)^{(n-1)^2+1}$$
For inverses, I think the same argument can be made as the above, hence an upper bound after considering inverses is given by
$$n^{n^2}-2n^2(n-1)^{(n-1)^2+1}$$
I have no idea how to even get started with associativity!
Further, I have never been fantastic at counting problems, so I am sure I made a flaw in my argument thus far.
Any progress or criticisms are very much welcome.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2598998/104041)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fleshing out my comment on Ethan's answer, and assuming the conjecture that "most groups are $2$-groups", we can get an asymptotic upper bound as well.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/241381/655547) we see that $\mu(p,n)$, the number of groups of order $p^n$, grows like

$$
\mu(p,n) = p^{\left ( \frac{2}{27} + O(n^{-1/3}) \right ) n^3}.
$$

So when $p = 2$, if we set $N = 2^n$ we find there are roughly

$$
\frac{N! \ 2^{\left ( \frac{2}{27} + O(\log(N)^{-1/3}) \right ) \log(N)^3}}{N^{N^2}}
$$

which, for $n \gg 1$ (so we can quietly ignore the $O(n^{-1/3})$ term), is even more roughly

$$
\frac{N! \ N^{\frac{2}{27} \log(N)^2}}{N^{N^2}}.
$$

Since this is conjectured to be as big as possible, if we combine with Ethan's answer (which is obviously the smallest possible) we find

$$
\frac{N!}{N^{N^2}} 
\leq \text{ the fraction of group operations on a set of size $N$ } 
\leq \frac{N! \ N^{\frac{2}{27} \log(N)^2}}{N^{N^2}}.
$$

Since $N! \approx \left ( \frac{N}{e} \right )^N$, which dominates the $N^{\log(N)^2}$ term that we've picked up, these bounds are deceptively close together (especially when placed next to the $N^{N^2}$ term).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer. (I suspect there is no good answer.)

The probability will be quite small. If $n$ is prime there are just $n!$ ways to define a binary operation that yields a group, since the only group of prime order is cyclic. All you can do is rename the elements.

As you note, there are $n^{n^2}$ binary operations.
$$
\frac{n!}{n^{n^2}} \text{ is very small }.
$$

Comment: I also suspect there is no good answer, but this is necessarily the "worst case." I would be fascinated to see any similar result on $2$-groups, but I would guess even that is unknown.

Comment: On the other side of the spectrum, we suspect "most groups" have size $2^n$ for some $n$. We know there are [49,487,365,422 groups of order $1024$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241369/more-than-99-of-groups-of-order-less-than-2000-are-of-order-1024), and if we multiply by $1024!$ to get all the operations (rather than just the isomorphism type) we have the best chance of getting a large fraction of operations to be groups. But according to [sage](https://sagemath.org) this is roughly $1.38 \times 10^{-3153878}$. So even in the best case, we get something "very small".

Comment: @ElliotG -- I had the same idea, haha

Comment: This is a great observation! Another idea is that if $n = p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_m^{k_m}$ counting abelian groups is given by the product of partitions of each $k_i$, so the probability that a random binary operation forms an abelian group is $\frac{n^{n^2}}{\prod_{i\leq m}P(k_i)}$ where $P(i)$ counts the partitions. Maybe then one could try to throw out commutativity from this?